# Locating WebElement using different locators(NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am having problem with locating `WebElement` using different locators. In the below html tag I tried locating the "write a review" `WebElement` with different locators like `linkText`,`xpath`,`classname` but still getting `NoSuchElementException`

-->`url https://www.tripadvisor.in/`-->`search for Club Mahindra`-->`click on Club Mahindra`-->`click on write a review`.

```
    <a href="/UserReview-g641714-d1156207-Club_Mahindra_Madikeri_Coorg- 
    Madikeri_Kodagu_Coorg_Karnataka.html" target="_blank" class="ui_button 
    primary">Write a review</a>
```

Locators used

- `By.xpath("//*[@id="component_12"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a")`
- `By.xpath("//a[@href='/UserReview-g641714-d1156207- 
  Club_Mahindra_Madikeri_Coorg-Madikeri_Kodagu_Coorg_Karnataka.html']")`
- `By.className("ui_button primary")`
- `By.linkText("Write a review")`

I am really confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your attempts of solving this? What xpaths, class names, and so on, you have used?

Comment: By.xpath("//*[@id="component_12"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a") and By.xpath("//a[@href='/UserReview-g641714-d1156207-Club_Mahindra_Madikeri_Coorg-Madikeri_Kodagu_Coorg_Karnataka.html']") , By.className("ui_button primary"), By.linkText("Write a review")

Comment: Are you using any explicit or implicit waits? Maybe simply, the page is not loaded when you are trying to click on the button.

Comment: Yes i tried with both the wait ...also tried with action class but still it shows NoSuchElementException @Jonah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tired to analyse and implement the same. Below are my findings:

-> Application waiting time is more as there are lots of dynamic loads applicable for the page.

-> Proper waits needs to be implemented

-> Check whether all the pages are getting opened in the same tab or clicking on each link is redirecting to new tabs, if so then we have to switch to that particular window.

-> Below code works like a pro for me.

```
    driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    WebElement ele1 =  
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()='Where to?']")));
    ele1.click();

    WebElement ele2= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Where to?']")));
    ele2.sendKeys("club mahindra, india");

    WebElement ele3= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Search for ')]")));
    ele3.click();
    WebElement ele4= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Club Mahindra Madikeri, Coorg')]")));
    ele4.click();   //this click leads to a new tab 

    Set<String> winHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();  

    for(String str : winHandles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(str);
    }
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    WebElement ele;
    int i=1;
    while(true) {
        try {
         ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()='Write a review']")));
         break;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print(i++);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(ele);
    ele.click();
    System.out.println("Clicked on the 'Write a review button'");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
  //a[contains(text(),'Write a review')]
```

Comment: I tried using the xpath but still stuck with NoSuchElementException .It also doesn't worked